# LightSwitch System.IO.File.Create

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have create a lightSwitch application, and a button to create a file, but I get the error message "File operation not permitted. Access to path 'D:\temp\Application1\Application1\lightswitch.txt' is denied." This is a Security Exception, how do I elevate the trust to be able to create a file 
thanks
stuart

Answer (score 1):

You may want to simply upload the file to a directoy that is allowed. See: http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/35/Saving-Files-To-File-System-With-LightSwitch-Uploading-Files.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Deploy as desktop application ' out of browser '